# create view over 2 databases into a third one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, data-integration

I have rwo Databases, let's say DB1 and DB2 which DB2 is a copy of DB1 and exactly the same.I also have an empty third Database named Main.How can i create a view within the Main database from the tables of DB1 and DB2.For example if [person].[person] is a table in DB1 and DB2,something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v1 AS
SELECT * FROM [DB1].[person].[person] 
UNION
SELECT * FROM [DB2].[person].[person];
```

P.S. All 3 databases are on the same server!

Answer (score 1):

For creating view, you are not needed to have 3rd database as view is nothing but virtual table which is the combination of 2 or more different tables in same or different database or server.

For better understanding of SQL views, please refer [SQL Views](http://fresh2refresh.com/sql-tutorial/sql-views/).

Comment: I know but i need to issue query over a single interface, smthg like a view. what other options do i have?